# Add A Column to A Data Frame by Comparing every 2 Consecutive Rows of A Column for Minimum and Maximum Value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing a column called `Values` among other columns within which I want to make a comparison of every consecutive 2 rows for minimum value, print `TRUE` to a row that has the minimum and `FALSE` to the other row that is maximum. My row consideration is in `1,2`, `3,4`, `5,6`, `7,8`, `9,10`,`11,12`, `etc`. In such, my row-wise comparison is `odd and even` and not even row with odd row.

```
library(reshape2)
set.seed(199)
MB_RMSE_sd1 <-  runif(12, min = 0, max = 2)
TMB_RMSE_sd1 <- runif(12, min = 0, max = 2)
MB_RMSE_sd3 <-  runif(12, min = 2, max = 5)
TMB_RMSE_sd3 <- runif(12, min = 2, max = 5)
MB_RMSE_sd5 <- runif(12, min = 5, max = 10)
TMB_RMSE_sd5 <- runif(12, min = 5, max = 10)
MB_RMSE_sd10 <-  runif(12, min = 7, max = 16)
TMB_RMSE_sd10 <- runif(12, min = 7, max = 16)
MB_MAE_sd1 <-  runif(12, min = 0, max = 2)
TMB_MAE_sd1 <- runif(12, min = 0, max = 2)
MB_MAE_sd3 <-  runif(12, min = 2, max = 5)
TMB_MAE_sd3 <- runif(12, min = 2, max = 5)
MB_MAE_sd5 <-  runif(12, min = 5, max = 10)
TMB_MAE_sd5 <- runif(12, min = 5, max = 10)
MB_MAE_sd10 <-  runif(12, min = 7, max = 16)
TMB_MAE_sd10 <- runif(12, min = 7, max = 16)

ID <- rep(rep(c("N10_AR0.8", "N10_AR0.9", "N10_AR0.95", "N15_AR0.8", "N15_AR0.9", "N15_AR0.95", "N20_AR0.8", "N20_AR0.9", "N20_AR0.95", "N25_AR0.8", "N25_AR0.9", "N25_AR0.95"), 2), 1)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, MB_RMSE_sd1, TMB_MAE_sd1, MB_RMSE_sd3, TMB_MAE_sd3, MB_RMSE_sd5, TMB_MAE_sd5, MB_RMSE_sd10, TMB_MAE_sd10)
reshapp1 <- reshape2::melt(df1, id = "ID")

NEWDAT <- data.frame(value = reshapp1$value, year = reshapp1$ID, n = rep(rep(c("10", "15", "20", "25"), each = 3), 16), Colour = rep(rep(c("RMSE_MB", "RMSE_TMB", "MAE_MB", "MAE_TMB"), each = 12), 4), sd = rep(rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each = 48), 1),  phi = rep(rep(c("0.8", "0.9", "0.95"), 16), 4))

NEWDAT$sd <- with(NEWDAT, factor(sd, levels = sd, labels = paste("sd =", sd)))
NEWDAT$year <- factor(NEWDAT$year, levels = NEWDAT$year[1:12])
NEWDAT$n <- with(NEWDAT, factor(n, levels = n, labels = paste("n = ", n)))
##################################
head(NEWDAT)
#   value       year       n  Colour     sd  phi
# 1 0.05624369  N10_AR0.8 n =  10 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8
# 2 1.32718190  N10_AR0.9 n =  10 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9
# 3 1.42121934 N10_AR0.95 n =  10 RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95
# 4 0.56366171  N15_AR0.8 n =  15 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8
# 5 0.02666847  N15_AR0.9 n =  15 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9
# 6 0.48640038 N15_AR0.95 n =  15 RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95
```

**What I Want**

```
NEWDAT1 <- dplyr::mutate(NEWDAT, Highlight = value == min...)
head(NEWDAT1)
 #      value       year       n  Colour     sd  phi    Highlight
# 1 0.05624369  N10_AR0.8 n =  10 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8    TRUE
# 2 1.32718190  N10_AR0.9 n =  10 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9    FALSE
# 3 1.42121934 N10_AR0.95 n =  10 RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95    FALSE
# 4 0.56366171  N15_AR0.8 n =  15 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8    TRUE
# 5 0.02666847  N15_AR0.9 n =  15 RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9    TRUE
# 6 0.48640038 N15_AR0.95 n =  15 RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- NEWDAT %>% 
    mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(Highlight = case_when(index %% 2 != 0 & value < lead(value) ~ TRUE,
                                 index %% 2 == 0 & value < lag(value) ~ TRUE,
                                 TRUE ~ FALSE))

> df2
         value       year       n   Colour     sd  phi index Highlight
1   0.05624369  N10_AR0.8 n =  10  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8     1      TRUE
2   1.32718190  N10_AR0.9 n =  10  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9     2     FALSE
3   1.42121934 N10_AR0.95 n =  10  RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95     3     FALSE
4   0.56366171  N15_AR0.8 n =  15  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8     4      TRUE
5   0.02666847  N15_AR0.9 n =  15  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9     5      TRUE
6   0.48640038 N15_AR0.95 n =  15  RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95     6     FALSE
7   1.37879656  N20_AR0.8 n =  20  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8     7     FALSE
8   1.33491011  N20_AR0.9 n =  20  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.9     8      TRUE
9   0.56152963 N20_AR0.95 n =  20  RMSE_MB sd = 1 0.95     9      TRUE
10  0.74926950  N25_AR0.8 n =  25  RMSE_MB sd = 1  0.8    10     FALSE
```